# Vb.Net update Datagridview in main form when save data in another form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, auto-update

This my function to display data from sql server to Datagridview

```
 Private Function getpdfinfo1() As DataTable
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    Dim dtpi As New DataTable
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("pdflib.My.MySettings.hazimdbConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select idpdf as  ID,pdfname as  Title, categories as Categories , extension as Extension from pdfinfo where ( username='" & Label10.Text & "' ) ", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dtpi.Load(reader)
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dtpi

End Function
```

And in Main Form Load even I am calling the function `getpdfinfo1()` as shown below

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = getpdfinfo1()
End Sub
```

I save data from another form. The button click event to save data is as shown below

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into pdfinfo (pdfname,pdfdata,categories,username,iduser,extension) values (@pdfname,@pdfdata,@categories,@username,@iduser,@extension) ", connection)
        connection.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pdfname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@categories", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = TextBox4.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@iduser", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Label6.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@extension", SqlDbType.NChar, 10)).Value = Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName)
        Dim fs As New FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim file() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pdfdata", SqlDbType.VarBinary)).Value = file
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Label8.Text = "Upload Completed"
```

> So  I want when clicked Save button in (save data Form) then the
>   Datagridview** in Main Form (Form 2) will be updated automatically.
>
> Or, How to create function update Datagridview when Sql data changes.

Comment: Like so many people, you are doing this the wrong way around.  You don't save data to the database in the second form and then get that data back from the database in the first form.  You get the data from the second form into the first form and update the `DataTable` that is bound to your grid first.  That means that the first form is already updated with the new data before the database.  You then save the changes from the `DataTable` to the database using the same data adapter that you used to get the data in the first place. That means using a data adapter rather than a data reader.

Comment: Datagridview  just for display in main form

Comment: That isn't relevant.  You can do it the way you want or you can do it the right way.  Your choice.

Comment: I have solved it and i will post the solutions. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The getpdfinfo1 function is private, make it public function and call this function in the save button click event. To call the functions from other form you can just prefix the form name.function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a dataclass containing all the data you want to modify in Form 2
2. Declare a dataclass property (friend or public) in form 2
3. Refresh/fill the dataclass when pressing Save on Form 2
4. Set From 2 Save-button as acceptbutton
5. Call Form 2 from the Main Form an check on dialogresult OK
6. When dialogresult = OK Refresh datagridview / save data using
   sql/...
7. Be carefull if you don't want to write/read sql first to refresh your dgv, that your sql transaction was completed succesfull. This is imortant to prevent users would see different data in the datagridview than there is in your database.